# Soundcloud players are in the wrong place when page reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, soundcloud

I have a page with multiple Soundcloud players loaded via jquery.

When the page is first loaded the players are in the correct order. If the tab is closed and reopened (using Chrome's ctrl+shift+t) or if you go to a different page and press the back button then the players are reloaded in the incorrect positions.

I've put a simple demonstration project at https://github.com/iainx/sc-bug-test.

For Chrome and Safari you can reproduce it like so

1. Load page and the 3 players should be in the order Double Dagger, Jonathan Rado and CFCF
2. Go to another page
3. Press back button to return to the test page. Sometimes the players are no longer in the correct order, but the titles are still in the correct order, which suggests to me that the jquery is selecting the correct articles.

The code in question is

```
$(function() {
    tracks = ["http://soundcloud.com/thrilljockey/double-dagger-heretics-hymn", "http://soundcloud.com/woodsist/jonathan-rado-faces", "http://soundcloud.com/cfcf/camera"];

    function updateTrack(trackUrl, playerNumber) {

        $.getJSON('http://soundcloud.com/oembed?callback=?',
                  {format: 'js', url: trackUrl, iframe:'true'},
                  function(data) {
                      var articleDiv = $('#player' + playerNumber);
                      var playerDiv = articleDiv.find('.player');

                      var position = playerDiv.position();
                      playerDiv.html(data['html']);

                      var titleDiv = articleDiv.find("header"); 
                      titleDiv.text(data['title']);
                  });
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        updateTrack(tracks[i - 1], i);
    }
});
```

It works fine in Firefox (on Linux and OSX), but it breaks in both Chrome (on both Linux and OSX), Safari (on OSX) and Epiphany (another WebKit browser on Linux).

Is there anything silly going on with my code, or is this some obscure bug in either Soundcloud or even Webkit?

Comment: You used a closure, so I don't see how they could be out of order. Can you check the value of `playerNumber` in the callback and verify that it's correct?

Comment: Yes,the playerNumber is correct in the callbacks.if I print playerDiv.html before changing it,it even gives the correct old HTML, and the titleDiv.text call changes the correct title every time